# How to attach files to a Visualforce Email Template with a custom component/controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, class

How do I execute an apex class from a visualforce email template. I tried to use an apex component with an action function. The visualforce emailtemplate errors add apex:form tags around action funtion, when I do this it errors me to remove them. So im stuck in a loop. Is this a bug or does anyone how to achieve this in another way??

Comment: As far as I know you can't use forms or JavaScript actions in a Visualforce Email Template. The ability to use a apex controller to generate a dynamic email exists because the basic functionality only allows you to use two objects (contact, lead, account and other object of your choice), so if you have to list child records for one of those, for example, you can use the controller to do that, but you won't be able to use a form. Have you tried removing your `apex:form` tag, and all actions?

Comment: I tried removing the apex:form tag, and all actions, but the how do i get my class to execute the attachments of the email?

Comment: What do you mean "execute the attachments"? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to attach files to a visualforce email template  from notes and attachments from opportunity record. I have seen many examples were the link is generated but the use requires login which is not an option in my case. So i tried the route to use a component controller which gives me te apex:form issue because i cant use the action funtion whitout the form tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your last comment, I suppose you want to send an email with files attached to it. You can't do this with a controller on the email template, as far as I know. What you can do is create a class to gather the information you need (the record and the attachments).

You should be able to create a single email message (using `Messaging.SingleEmailMessage`), and then attach your files to the message using the `Messaging.EmailFileAttachment` class.

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage sem = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
sem.setTemplateId(template_id); // your visualforce template id
sem.setWhatId(opp_id); // this would be your opportunity or whatever custom object you are using the template with
sem.setTargetObjectId(contact_id); // this would be your user, contact or account id

// create your attachment
Messaging.EmailFileAttachment efa = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
efa.setBody(att.Body); // this will get the attachment's Body
efa.setFileName(att.Name); // this will set the name of the file that will be attached to the email message
efa.setContentType(att.ContentType); // specify what kind of content that is (usually the same as your Attachment record)

// attach your file to the email message
sem.setFileAttachments(new List<Messaging.EmailFileAttachment>{efa});
```